# Where can I find raw text, ascii, or binary data from the GALEX satellite?

Tags: star, observational-astronomy, data-analysis, space-telescope, stellar-astrophysics

I am looking for stars in the GALEX data through the GALEX data using GALEXview and plugging in their Henry Draper Numbers

http://galex.stsci.edu/galexview/

But the task is tedious by hand. Is there any place that I can look to find the raw text, ascii, or binary data? I want to be able to simply pull the data I need in one go with a program, rather than copying it down by hand. Currently I'm having to look through the data point star by star.

http://galex.stsci.edu/GR6/

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you after?  Specific stars or the GALEX catalog?  The GALEX data are made available through [MAST](http://archive.stsci.edu/). You can check out their [user guide](https://mast.stsci.edu/portal/Mashup/Clients/Mast/data/html/MastHelp.html) to see how to get data.